WebRTC is adding the remote video without clicking on answer button
I am working on a WebRTC application using JavaScript and WebSockets. The issue I am encountering is that the remote video stream is being added automatically without the user clicking the "Answer" button. I need the remote video to only be added after the "Answer" button is clicked.I am using websoket to handle signaling in django framework.Any advice is acceptable,thanks in advance.
  const url = "ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/wc/?group=manish";
  const socket = new WebSocket(url);
  let localVideo = document.getElementById("localVideo");
  let remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");
  let peerConnection;
  let iceCandidatesQueue = [];
  let awaitingAnswer = false;

  function createPeerConnection() {
    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();

    peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
      if (event.candidate) {
        console.log("Sending ICE candidate:", event.candidate);
        socket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "ice", ice: event.candidate }));
      }
    };

    peerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
      console.log("Received remote track:", event.track);
      if (event.track.kind === "video") {
        console.log("Received video track");
        if (remoteVideo.srcObject !== event.streams[0]) {
          remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
          console.log("Remote video stream added.");
        }
      }
    };

    peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
      console.log("ICE connection state:", peerConnection.iceConnectionState);
    };

    peerConnection.onsignalingstatechange = () => {
      console.log("Signaling state:", peerConnection.signalingState);
    };
  }

  function getUserMediaAndAddTracks() {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
      .then((stream) => {
        localVideo.srcObject = stream;
        stream
          .getTracks()
          .forEach((track) => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error accessing media devices:", error);
      });
  }

  socket.onopen = (e) => {
    console.log("Connection opened:", e);
    createPeerConnection();
    getUserMediaAndAddTracks();
  };

  socket.onmessage = (event) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log("Data received:", data);

    if (data.type === "sdp") {
      const sdp = new RTCSessionDescription(data.sdp);
      console.log("SDP received:", sdp);

      if (sdp.type === "offer") {
        handleOffer(sdp);
      } else if (sdp.type === "answer") {
        handleAnswer(sdp);
      }
    } else if (data.type === "ice") {
      handleIce(data.ice);
    }
  };

  socket.onclose = (e) => {
    console.log("Connection closed:", e);
  };

  socket.onerror = (e) => {
    console.error("WebSocket error:", e);
  };

  document
    .getElementById("send_message_btn")
    .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      socket.send(JSON.stringify({ message: "Hello World", type: "message" }));
    });

  document.getElementById("sdp_btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (peerConnection.signalingState === "stable") {
      peerConnection
        .createOffer()
        .then((offer) => peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer))
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Sending SDP offer...");
          socket.send(
            JSON.stringify({
              type: "sdp",
              sdp: peerConnection.localDescription,
            })
          );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error creating offer:", error);
        });
    } else {
      console.warn(
        "Cannot create offer in signaling state:",
        peerConnection.signalingState
      );
    }
  });

  document.getElementById("answer").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (peerConnection.signalingState === "have-remote-offer") {
      peerConnection
        .createAnswer()
        .then((answer) => peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer))
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Sending SDP answer...");
          socket.send(
            JSON.stringify({
              type: "sdp",
              sdp: peerConnection.localDescription,
            })
          );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error creating answer:", error);
        });
    } else {
      console.warn(
        "Cannot create answer in signaling state:",
        peerConnection.signalingState
      );
    }
  });

  function handleOffer(offer) {
    if (peerConnection.signalingState === "stable") {
      peerConnection
        .setRemoteDescription(offer)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Remote description set, creating answer...");
          return peerConnection.createAnswer();
        })
        .then((answer) => {
          console.log("Answer created, setting local description...");
          return peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Local description set, sending SDP answer...");
          socket.send(
            JSON.stringify({
              type: "sdp",
              sdp: peerConnection.localDescription,
            })
          );
          processIceCandidates();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error handling offer:", error);
        });
    } else {
      console.warn(
        "Received offer in invalid state:",
        peerConnection.signalingState
      );
    }
  }

  function handleAnswer(answer) {
    if (peerConnection.signalingState === "have-local-offer") {
      peerConnection
        .setRemoteDescription(answer)
        .then(() => {
          console.log(
            "Remote description set from answer, processing ICE candidates..."
          );
          processIceCandidates();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error handling answer:", error);
        });
    } else {
      console.warn(
        "Received answer in invalid state:",
        peerConnection.signalingState
      );
    }
  }

  function handleIce(candidate) {
    console.log("Handling ICE candidate:", candidate);
    if (peerConnection.remoteDescription) {
      peerConnection
        .addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error adding ICE candidate:", error);
        });
    } else {
      iceCandidatesQueue.push(candidate);
    }
  }

  function processIceCandidates() {
    while (iceCandidatesQueue.length) {
      const candidate = iceCandidatesQueue.shift();
      peerConnection
        .addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error adding queued ICE candidate:", error);
        });
    }
  }
});

